# Three.js-- having text overlays appear on screen

Tags: three.js

I'd like to create some mechanism that provides a text overlay on top of my 3D scene at certain times (such as when clicking a mouse button for instance.)

I'm going over the tutorials on [github](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/) and notice things like the `THREE.TextGeometry` class.  Using it I can put 3D text in the scene, but it may be a bit more than I need-- what I'm really after is a way to put some text on, say, a black background, overlay it on the scene, then move it out of the way when done.  Does anyone know of good ways to do this in three.js?  (If the `THREE.TextGeometry` class is a good way to do this that's fine, I'm just not sure how to do the overlay bit.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use HTML. It's super easy and powerful especially if you just need an overlay. With CSS, you can also achieve things like semi-transparent background. If you want to have it "blend" to scene, i.e. have perspective etc. you can use `THREE.CSS3DRenderer` which will transform divs based on camera you supply.

Comment: Thank you.  Do you know of any examples out there I can use as templates, that are especially good?

Comment: Just about every three.js example overlays some info text on top of the page. If you were interested about the `CSS3DRenderer`, the simplest one appears to be [css3d_sandbox](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/css3d_sandbox.html)